# “assignment to free variable” warning after defvar

Tags: variables, byte-compilation

The compiler will issue a warning message

> Warning: assignment to free variable `-/var`

if you *evaluate* the following *forms*:

```lisp
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(defvar -/var)
(byte-compile (let (_)
                (lambda ()
                  -/var)))
```

But if you

- remove the local binding of `_`, then *evaluate* the following *forms*:

  ```lisp
  ;;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
  (defvar -/var)
  (byte-compile (let ()
                  (lambda ()
                    -/var)))
  ```

or

- *`byte-compile-file`* the entire *file* stead of using `byte-compile`:

  ```lisp
  ;;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
  (defvar -/var)
  (let (_)
    (lambda ()
      -/var))
  ```

Everything goes well.

Why would this happen?
I see no difference among the above snippets.

---

emacs-version: 29.1 
system-configuration: x86_64-w64-mingw32

Comment: @phils: Did you notice the source code comment for `dlet`? Perhaps they fix this bug but forgot to update the comment.

Comment: @phils: I tested it in v29.1 and v30.0.50; both behaved as the question description mentioned. How did you test it? by `-Q`?

Comment: @phils: It’s my fault - I didn't state how to test it clearly. Just evaluate that form, instead of byte-compiling the file. Sorry again.

Comment: @phils: In this example, yes, I could separate these two forms. However, this is a simplified version of the actual code. In the context of the original code, I prefer using backquote-comma. ||| I just cannot figure out why the compiler issues a warning. "`defvar` a SYMBOL without VALUE to make that symbol special locally." I already `defvar`ed it and seems that the `defvar` form and the `lambda` form are in the same lexical scope.

Comment: It seems like either a false-positive or a false-negative warning.  Or at least (as I found in my initial test), both versions of the file byte-compile to the exact same code, so we'd need the byte-code interpreter to execute this differently to the plain lisp interpreter for there to be any difference.  That might be the case, but *potentially* the issue only exists in the code which generates the warning.

Comment: @phils: I updated the question description and removed the quasi-quoting to make it more realistic. ||| I think this behavior is caused by *some information not being shared* between the **interpreter** and the **byte-compiler** called by `byte-compile`. Obviously, I still don't have a deep enough understanding of the implementation details of Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you read the answer, the problem and the answer are only helpful for those want to explicitly call the byte compiler and want to learn the detail on how lexical binding and dynamic binding interact with each other in Emacs. Simply adhering to the usually coding convention can completely avoid the situation.

---

On 29.1, the minimal reproduced example should be like

```lisp
(defvar foo) ;; foo must be fresh and unbound to reproduce the problem.

(let ()
  (lambda () (setq foo t)))
(closure (foo t) nil (setq foo t))

(let (_)
  (lambda () (setq foo t)))
(closure (t) nil (setq foo t)) ;; Warn about free variable if compiled.
```

They produce different closure object thus byte compiler produce different messages.

The difference of results in 29.1 is likely due to

```lisp
(let (_) ... )
```

has the semantic of introducing a new scope (mentioned in the manual but didn't into any of the detail of this), thus it would nullify the `(defvar ...` declaration in global scope. The closure produced reflected this.

It can thus conclude that **it is expected for the byte compiler to produce a warning here**.

There are a few edge case behavior (tested with 29.1) worth to be mentioned: `defvar` does not need to be evaluated to take effect, and does not seem to produced any side effect when evaluated if no binding is provided. The interpreter and compiler would search the `defvar` declarations in lexical binding mode to handle their effect. So simply comment/uncomment `defvar` declarations in top level of the scratch buffer without reevaluate it can affect the byte code produced. And there are too many ways fool the interpreter/compiler by hide the `defvar` declarations from them.

`defconst` works in a similar way to `defvar`.

However, once used `defvar`/`setq`/`defconst` to binding the variable, the variable itself does become "permanently" special
and `makunbound` can not revert the effect, but `unintern` can.

Remember that, *`(defvar foo)` and `(defvar foo nil)` has
different meaning and the behavior can be different.*

---

On 28.2 the result is also different, although the byte compiler would not generate a complain for the free variable. Whether `foo` is bound or undeclared would not make a difference to the result.

[image]

---

Op mentioned the FIXME comment in `dlet`. However, that is not a bug
at all. The problem mentioned in `dlet` is because the byte
compiler would optimize

```lisp
(let () body) => (progn body)
```

which is a behavior decided before lexical scoping was introduced. Thus the verbose `(let (_) ...)` is used.

The `(let (_) body)` expression itself is not a magic, it is from `(let (a) body)` where `a` is not used in `body`, the only difference is byte compiler would warn if `a` is an unused variable, and might produce more efficient byte code for `_` version. Actually you can use `_a` to nullify the unused variable warning and it would produce the same bytecode.

```lisp
(lambda ()
  (let (_)
    (defvar abc-foo)
    (let (abc-foo)
      (setq abc-foo 1))))

(lambda ()
  (let (a)
    (defvar abc-foo)
    (let (abc-foo)
      (setq abc-foo 1))))

(lambda ()
  (let (_a)
    (defvar abc-foo)
    (let (abc-foo)
      (setq abc-foo 1))))
```

The only magical thing is actually `defvar`:

```lisp
(equal
(byte-compile
 (lambda ()
  (progn
    (defvar abc-foo)
    (let (abc-foo)
      (setq abc-foo 1)))))

(byte-compile
 (lambda ()
  (let (_) ;; with or without _ produced same result
    (defvar abc-foo)
    (let (abc-foo)
      (setq abc-foo 1))))))
;; t
```